# javascript - printing form values to console.log giving undefined error

Tags: javascript, html, forms, undefined, console.log

I was trying to print form values on submit to console.log to test. But getting a undefined message. Can't figure out where I am going wrong exactly. I have gone through various answers on StackOverflow but still no luck. Here is the code -

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <label class="required">* required </label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control inputArea" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name *">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control inputArea" id="email" placeholder="Email *">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control inputArea" id="phn" placeholder="Phone Number *">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    var formInput = document.querySelectorAll('#fullname, #email, #phn');

    document.querySelector('form.form-inline').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(formInput.value);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting undefined because `forminput` is not a single object it has multiple `objects` which doesn't have property `value`.

You can get value by index like below

```
console.log(formInput[0].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are querying the form before the values are inputted.  The first line of your script should be inside the event listener:

```
<script>
    document.querySelector('form.form-inline').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formInput = document.querySelectorAll('#fullname, #email, #phn');
        console.log(formInput.value);
    });
</script>
```

The values are being query-ed on page-load.  You need to wait until the user submits before you check the values.

Comment: Values are not being get on page load only object is getting on page load.

Comment: Thanks @Calteran :) The solution provided by Leopard worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Hope it helps!

```js
 function myFunction(){
  var a = document.getElementById("fullname").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("phn").value;

  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  console.log(c);

  return false;
 }
```

```html
<form class="form-inline" onsubmit = " return myFunction()">
  <label class="required">* required </label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control inputArea" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name *">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control inputArea" id="email" placeholder="Email *">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control inputArea" id="phn" placeholder="Phone Number *">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @HenryDev that worked! But because Leopard answered first, I would have to mark his answer. Cheers mate :)